# Сравнить версии приложения

Tags: golang

Хочу сравнить версию приложения и выявить старая версия или новая версия. Но не знаю как это сделать :(

Код:

```
var version = [2]uint8{0,5} // version 0.5
```

То есть нужно сделать как-то так что если версия больше чем `version`, допустим `[2]uint8{0,10}` -> выдать ошибку и если версия меньше, допустим `[2]uint8{0,2}` тогда тоже выдать ошибку. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Массивы (не слайсы!) в го можно сравнивать:

```golang
var (
    v1 = [2]int{0, 5}
    v2 = [2]int{0, 2}
    v3 = [2]int{0, 5}
)
fmt.Println(v1 == v3, v1 == v2)
// true false
```

А вообще, для сравнения версий лучше использовать библиотеки. В случае СемВера можно воспользоваться вот этой: https://godoc.org/github.com/blang/semver.

Comment: Ссылка на [семантическое версионирование](https://semver.org/lang/ru/) на русском.